# How to call a javascript function from a Repeater ItemCommand function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sweetalert

I am using SweetAlert in my Master Page and calling it from client page using following command

```
string msg = "Incomplete Profile";
Master.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "mufunc", "mufunc('" + msg + "','" + "info" + "');", true);
```

Same calling from a repeater item command is not working. Here is my block

```
if (e.CommandName.Equals("profile"))
 {
 if (lbl_UserName.Text == "Guest")
   {
    msg = "Incomplete Profile";
    Master.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "mufunc", "mufunc('" + msg + "','" + "info" + "');", true);
   }
 }
```

Comment: `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "mufunc", "mufunc('" + msg + "','" + "info" + "');", true);`  should be fine. Why Master?

Comment: The javascript function is written on MasterPage file . I also tried the code as rewriteten javascript block in child page and then called without using Master assembly

Comment: It will automatically come inside page, no need of that

Comment: I changed as per your suggestions even its not working from a repeater item command

Comment: I got this up thanks for that . I used ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript